# Python: Login none error

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt, mysql-python, mysql-connector-python

i'm making a login system for part of my coursework, where it querys the database to see if the data is correct. It works fine until I introduce a login that's not in the database. Is there anyway I can make the while working even after the mycursor.fetchone() gives the error for not fetching anything?

The code below is the subroutine I'm having issues with:

```
#the error message I'm receiving 
username, password = mycursor.fetchone()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

#the subroutine I'm having trouble with
def accept(self):
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(user, password, host, database)
        #create cursor between python and mysql
        mycursor = conn.cursor()

        query = """
            SELECT 
                username, password 
            FROM 
                UserInfo.User
            WHERE 
                username = %s AND password = %s
        """
        mycursor.execute(query, (self.textName.text(),self.textPass.text(), ))
        global username
        username, password = mycursor.fetchone()        
        #self.textName.text() and self.textPass.text() is the username and password entered by the user
        if username == self.textName.text() and password == self.textPass.text():
            self.GoToLogin()

        else:
            #the error message I want to display
            QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(
                self, 'Error', 'Username and password are incorrect')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `try except` block and ignore the exception that happens when the record is not found or if multiple records are found.

```
try:
   #db call
except (SpecificException, AnotherException):
    pass
```

It's good to catch specific exceptions than catch all exceptions but in this case you can just catch the global `Exception`

Also there is no reason to check again if the user and password are equal, since you're already passing that as part of the query.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the exceptions

Comment: That's what I meant. You're not handling the exception raised by `fetchone` when a user doesn't exist. That's why you should put that method call between `try-except` block and ignore the exception. So call the warning inside the except block and goto-login right after `fetchone`.